# Why are methods in Ruby documentation preceded by a hash sign?

Tags: ruby, documentation

When I see any Ruby method printed in text, it usually appears as:

```
Class#method
```

or

```
#method
```

Now, I would use:

```
Class.method
```

Why are all Ruby methods preceded by a pound sign? Is there any reason for it?

Comment: When does it date back to?

Comment: It was first used in the 1st edition of Programming Ruby, published in 2001: https://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/preface.html#S10 - the choice of notation was explained more clearly in the 2nd edition released in 2005.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [rdoc docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rdoc/rdoc/index.html) (emphasis mine):

> Names of classes, source files, and
>   any method names containing an
>   underscore or **preceded by a hash
>   character** are automatically
>   hyperlinked from comment text to their
>   description.

Answer (score 111):

Note that the convention is:

```
Class#method
```

rather than

```
object#method
```

In code you would have `object.method`, if `object` was an instance of `class`. The `#` convention is not used in code.

From [the RDoc documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/documentation-guidelines.html):

> Use :: for describing class methods, # for describing instance methods, and use . for example code.

Comment: Yes, sorry, Class#Method.  Thanks.

Comment: I know that # is not used in code, but why is it used at all?

Answer (score 31):

The # notation is used to refer to the canonical `instance` method, like `String#upcase`. The . notation is used to refer to the method of a particular instance, like `mystring.upcase`. The distinction is made to not imply that a class method 'upcase' exists.

Answer (score 20):

I just realized that none of the other answers touch the most trivial aspect of the question: why the `#` sign?

I have two theories:

1. It might come from Smalltalk, where symbols are written `#sym` (instead of `:sym`) as they are in Ruby. So, if you want to *refer* to a Method *object* (as opposed to *calling* a method), then you would call something like `Array >> #new.` (The `>>` is itself a method that returns the method passed to it. So, in Ruby that would be `Array.method :new`.) In Smalltalk documentation, methods are generally referred to as `Class>>method`, but in Ruby `Class:method` would have made more sense, except that it is easily confused with `Class::method`. Therefore, `Class#method` was chosen.
2. My other theory is that it simply was chosen because `#` is the comment character in Ruby.

A definitive answer can only be given by whoever invented that convention. If it was invented for the *Programming Ruby* book, that would be either Dave Thomas or Andy Hunt, but I kind of doubt that. The book came out in 2001, Ruby started in 1993, how were they referring to methods before then?

Comment: I've heard that the pragmatic programmers created the documentation for Ruby as well (they wanted to seed the documentation so that others would be "fooled" into adding to it). git can take you back to 1998, so you could check if `Class#method_name` happened before the prag progs added it.

Comment: I've since heard that documentation did exist before the prag progs started adding it into the source code.

Comment: Maybe it's imitating the look of the # anchor syntax in HTML. For example http://www.somesite.com/somepage#section.

Comment: @BHS I second this. Absent any definitive resources as to _why_ `#` was chosen, I've always found the most likely explanation to be the anchors used to jump to a particular method in the documentation - Java's use of the same convention is widely believed to be of that origin as well.

Answer (score 8):

The hash notation was introduced "Programming Ruby - The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide" first published in December 2000.

The "Preface" contains ["Notational Conventions"](https://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/preface.html#S10):

> Within the text, `Fred#doIt` is a reference to an instance method (`doIt`) of `class Fred`, while `Fred.new` [In some other Ruby documentation, you may see class methods written as `Fred::new`. This is perfectly valid Ruby syntax; we just happen to feel that `Fred.new` is less distracting to read.] is a class method, and `Fred::EOF` is a class constant.

This is clarified in the 2nd edition, published in October 2004:

> Within the text, `Fred#do_something` is a reference to an instance method (in this case `do_something`) of `class Fred`, `Fred.new` is a class method, and `Fred::EOF` is a class constant. The decision to use a hash character to indicate instance methods was a tough one: it isn’t valid Ruby syntax, but we thought that it was important to differentiate between the instance and class methods of a particular class. When you see us write `File.read`, you know we’re talking about the class method `read`. When instead we write `File#read`, we’re referring to the instance method `read`.

Ruby itself uses this notation:

```
> rvm use 1.9.3
Using ruby-1.9.3-p551

> Object.instance_method(:initialize)
=> #<UnboundMethod: Object(BasicObject)#initialize>
```

It was introduced and formalised by [Matz in February 2002](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/8210c254bee19294af67bcee0e8f5e02ebb39a60#diff-49b101b7fe030279d27d70ddc47b9210R6919-R6947):

```
commit 8210c254bee19294af67bcee0e8f5e02ebb39a60
Author: matz <matz@b2dd03c8-39d4-4d8f-98ff-823fe69b080e>
Date:   Tue Feb 5 07:56:31 2002 +0000

    * io.c (fptr_finalize): should raise error when fclose fails.

    * eval.c (method_inspect): proper output format to distinguish
      methods and singleton methods.


    git-svn-id: svn+ssh://ci.ruby-lang.org/ruby/trunk@2046 b2dd03c8-39d4-4d8f-98ff-823fe69b080e
```

Answer (score 7):

All the answers above you list  are correct.  The one thing I would add is that the documentation style you said you would perfer

> Class.method

would be easily confused with class methods.  Since you can call class methods in ruby using the above syntax:

```
class Foo
  def self.say_hi
    puts "hi"
  end
end

Foo.say_hi    # => prints "hi"
```

Answer (score 4):

This was mentioned in the [JS version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587896/refering-to-javascript-instance-methods-with-a-pound-hash-sign#2587971), but it seems likely this nomenclature [came from JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link) where the hash mark is translated directly into an on-page reference, e.g. `href="Component.html#getComponentAt(int, int)"`

Comment: Huh, I'd been wondering why Javadoc requires that usage, but I didn't expect the reason to be so banal.

Answer (score 1):

heff's answer (which I can't comment on due to lack of reputation), that Ruby followed JavaDoc's example, is the best guess in my view. The JavaDoc designers needed or wanted a way to distinguish package qualifiers (which they used the dot for) from class qualifiers (which they used the hash for). JavaDoc's @see and @link tags syntax looks like this:

```
@see   package.class#member [optional label]
{@link package.class#member [optional label]}
```

See the documentation of [JavaDoc's package.class variant of the @see tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#package.class) and the documentation of JavaDoc's @link tag, which heff already pointed to.

In JavaDoc, the package name can often be omitted, so that only the Class#member part remains, which looks equally strange as in Ruby, because Java code uses the Class.member syntax,
just as Ruby does.

It would be interesting to find out why the JavaDoc designers needed the differing syntax, while the Java compiler does fine with dots for both purposes.