# What does "class#method" mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are methods in ruby documentation preceded by a pound sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736120/why-are-methods-in-ruby-documentation-preceded-by-a-pound-sign)
>
> EDIT: Duplicate of [Why are methods in ruby documentation preceded by a pound sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736120/)

Hi,

I'm trying to learn Ruby for fun at my spare time with the free *Programming Ruby* book. It is mostly fairly straight forward but I kept seeing notations like this *KaraokeSong#to_s*, which is not really explained in the earlier chapters of the book.

I know it meant *<class>#<method>*  but it is something you can use in the code? or just a notation ruby programmers use to specifiy a method like *<class>::<method>* notation used by C++ programmers?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/736120/ . Interestingly, none of the answers to that question answer the most trivial aspect: why the # sign?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`#` = instance method

`::` = class method

Per [ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/documentation-guidelines.html):

> Use :: for describing class methods, # for describing instance methods, and use . for example code.

Comment: Are there any official docs anyone can link here? Or we are just supposed to believe community knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

From the rdoc docs:

> Names of classes, source files, and any method names containing an underscore or preceded by a hash character are automatically hyperlinked from comment text to their description.

BTW, I asked the same question some time ago :-)

Comment: really? I did browse through the list of suggestions before I ask the question. Anyway, so does it mean its just used for rdoc to generate document? So you can't really use class#method to say get the reference to a method object using this notation?

Comment: Yeah, it's not always easy to find stuff around here.