# Referring to javascript instance methods with a pound/hash sign

Tags: javascript, documentation, instance-methods

This question is similar to [Why are methods in Ruby documentation preceded by a hash sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736120/why-are-methods-in-ruby-documentation-preceded-by-a-pound-sign)

I understand why in Ruby instance methods are proceeded with a pound sign, helping to differentiate talking about `SomeClass#someMethod` from `SomeObject.someMethod` and allowing `rdoc` to work. And I understand that the authors of PrototypeJS admire Ruby (with good reason) and so they use the [hash mark convention in their documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/class/prototype/addmethods/).

My question is: is this a standard practice amongst JavaScript developers or is it just Prototype developers who do this?

Asked another way, is it proper for me to refer to instance methods in comments/documentation as `SomeClass#someMethod`? Or should my documentation refer to ``SomeClass.someMethod`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it comes from javadoc.

[http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#{@link}](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@link%7D)

Comment: Certainly the first place I saw it. It's by analogy to the URL page#fragment syntax for links.

Comment: Ah. It's specifically stating: package.class#member is any valid program element name that is referenced -- a package, class, interface, constructor, method or field name -- except that the character ahead of the member name should be a hash character (#).

Comment: "As stated, the hash character (#), rather than a dot (.) separates a member from its class. This enables the Javadoc tool to resolve ambiguities, since the dot also separates classes, nested classes, packages, and subpackages."

Comment: From the javadoc.html link in this answer you'll find the a lot of information. Relevant information and reasons for hash notation run a word search for:    "package.class#member" to put you in the right spot.

Comment: A more direct/complete link to the different syntaxes JavaDoc defines, which you might also see when somebody is using this notation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#package.class

Answer (score 13):

No, I have not yet met another JavaScript project that uses this notation.

Something like this is useful in JavaScript, though, because unlike in many languages `Class.methodName` would refer to classmethods like `String.fromCharCode`, not instance methods which is what you are more often talking about. The method invoked by `myinstance.methodName` would be not `MyClass.methodName` but `MyClass.prototype.methodName`, and `MyClass.prototype` is an annoyance to keep typing.

(The standard JS library confuses this by making many instance methods also have a corresponding classmethod. But they're different functions.)

> is it proepr for me to refer to instance methods in comments/documentation as SomeClass#someMethod?

Do what you like/find most readable. There's no standard here.

Comment: Good answer. So if you were reading my documentation and I consistently used # to designate instance methods, you think it would be clear to you?

Comment: It would be clear to me from other languages. I wouldn't expect JS authors to know it, but hopefully it's grokkable from context!

Comment: So apparently this project uses it: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L2957