# What does mean "Server(srv:http#Server, opts:Object)" in socket.io api doc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Mentioning above, I want to know about the meaning of special character in socket.io api document, link below.
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io#serversrvhttpserver-optsobject

At that document, some title use #, :, srv, and I can't understand what they mean.

Another question is, does anybody know about tutorial or guidance post of socket.io? The official document has only few examples and the explanation is insufficient to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent the last 12 weeks building a production app using socket.io, and I feel you with the documentation frustrations.

Dave's answer is exactly what I was going to tell you regarding the actual command.

Regarding decyphering the documentation:

- the colon ( : ) is used to specify the type of parameter being accepted.
- hashtag ( # ) seems to represent properties of a particular object.
- srv I'm not exactly sure, but I'm guessing it refers to the particular serve method you're opting to use.

If I'm correct about srv, why?  The specific syntax you use to bind socket.io can vary depending on what other npm modules you're using.  The [documentation on socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/) shows that there's different ways to go about this.

Comment: `srv` is the name of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

- `Server()` takes an `http#Server`, and the variable name is `srv`.
- It also takes an `Object` called `opts` (e.g., options).

It does not return anything. By contrast, look at `serveClient` a few lines lower:

```
Server#serveClient(v:Boolean):Server
```

The trailing `:Server` means it returns a `Server`.

(An `http.Server` is an event emitter class, covered in the NodeJS docs.)

Search the web for socket.io tutorials; requesting off-site resources is OT for SO.

Comment: Oh, I'm almost understanding. By the way, do there any special reason to use "#", rather than "." ? That's why i'm confused.

Comment: @casamia Because that's what people use? It's used in Java and Ruby as well, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/2587896/438992, http://stackoverflow.com/q/736120/438992, etc.