# Why do js classes not use public and private keywords?

Tags: javascript, oop, es6-class

So when they created es6 classes they just made everything public by default, and that was a bit odd to me but I just went with it, given I still used the older es5 style scope based classes.

Anyway a few years on now we are getting private members in classes, which seems great, but then you look at the synax:

```
somePublicVar = 10;
#somePrivateVar = 20;
```

As you can see we now have to prefix the private stuff with the hash/pound sign which seems a very odd choice given JS has `public` and `private` keywords which are reserved for future use, so now we want to differentiate between public and private why not just now do.

```
public somePublicVar = 10;
private somePrivateVar = 20;
```

So I am sure there is a technical reason why but I am struggling to find it, as it would seem now would be the perfect time to turn those `public` and `private` from reserved to "in use", making it a bit more explicit and obvious as to the access modifiers of a given member.

Comment: `#` is more concise, and requires only one word - I prefer it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referring to javascript instance methods with a pound/hash sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587896/referring-to-javascript-instance-methods-with-a-pound-hash-sign)

Comment: `concise: giving a lot of information clearly and in a few words; brief but comprehensive.` I would argue `#` doesn't convey anything, it's just a convention that was made up, why not any single unused symbol like `~` etc?

Comment: To be honest, I don't like it either, it looks like a comment at first glance. You need to *know* that it means 'private'.

Comment: @Grofit [`~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_NOT)) is not an unused symbol in JS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official [FAQ](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md) answers it:

> ### Why aren't declarations `private x`?
>
> This sort of declaration is what other languages use (notably Java),
>   and implies that access would be done with `this.x`. Assuming that
>   isn't the case (see above), in JavaScript this would silently create
>   or access a public field, rather than throwing an error. This is a
>   major potential source of bugs or invisibly making public fields which
>   were intended to be private.
>
> It also allows a symmetry between declaration and access, just as
>   there is for public fields:
>
> ```
> class A {
>   pub = 0;
>   #priv = 1;
>   m() {
>     return this.pub + this.#priv;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> <sub>https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-arent-declarations-private-x</sub>