# What is the # (sharp, number, pound, hash) sign used for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What are the various meanings of the Ruby sharp/number sign/pound/hash(#) symbol

How many contexts does the symbol `#` in Ruby have ?

I know that #` represents comment

```
# a comment
```

or 'convert to the value':

```
i = 1
print "#{i}" # simple example
```

---

However I also see some Ruby docs describe built-in methods like these:

```
Array#fill
File::file?
```

Why do they describe the same thing using 2 different symbols ?
I am new in Ruby. Thanks

Comment: For the second part of your question: `#` denotes an instance method and `::` denotes a class method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how **instance** method described:

```
Array#fill
```

So you can:

```
a = Array.new(2)
 => [nil, nil]
a.fill(42)
 => [42, 42]
```

This is how **class** method described:

```
String::new

s = String.new('abc')
 => "abc"
```

Answer (score 12):

In Perl, # is used for commenting, and since Perl is an 'ancestor' of Ruby, the role was carried over.

The `"#{}"` syntax is called 'interpolation' and the pound was picked most likely because interpolation is similar in a sense to commenting, because you are changing the context of your code (in this case to another context for execution)

The # following a Class name is just meant to indicate the following identifier is a method of that Class, and is just a convention. Read more about it here: [Why are methods in Ruby documentation preceded by a hash sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736120/why-are-methods-in-ruby-documentation-preceded-by-a-hash-sign)

Answer (score 2):

The `::` is interesting, it acts similarly to the `.` in that you can call methods via both

```
Car::is_hybrid?
```

and

```
car.is_hybrid?
```

As you will see in most code though `.` is preferred for methods.

One case where `::` is often preferred is where you have constant in the class and you will see this in system calls such as `Math::PI` or ones you create, e.g. `ThePentagon::NUMBER_OF_BUILDING_SIDES`

Answer (score 1):

Just to show you as an example,that Ruby shows instance method preceded with the symbol `#` and class methods preceded with the symbol `.`.

```
class Foo
  def self.foo;end
  def bar;end
end

p Foo.method(:foo) # => #<Method: Foo.foo>
p Foo.new.method(:bar) # => #<Method: Foo#bar>
```